# different config value depending on running or debugging tests

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

In VSCode, there's an feature, that allows you to [**Run tests** and **Debug tests**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIOTm.png), shown just above the test function. In my current project, i'm using **py.test**. I've already customized py.test, so it runs in two threads:

```
"python.unitTest.pyTestArgs": [
    "-n2"
],
```

And here's my question: could I pass different parameters to py.test, depending on what i clicked: **Run tests** or **Debug tests**?

I want to pass `-q` while *running*, so I don't get my output bloated with tons of unwanted information, and pass `-s --verbose-debug-log` while *debugging*, because there I need full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've accidentally found answer to my question:

You could specify different launch options that would be [chooseable here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuA6t.png) via *launch.json* file

The entry there would be something like this:

```
(...)
    {
        "name": "Python: Debug with verbose log",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "env": {},
        "args": [
            "-s",
            "--verbose-debug-log"
        ],
        "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    },
(...)
```